# Windows 10 hide the user name on the start menu using gpo

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

Trying to use GPO to hide/remove the username in the start menu in Windows 10. I can't seem to find the entry in GPO has anyone done this already? Version of Windows 10 Pro 20H2

[image]

Comment: Other than the necessary management (log out, restart) in the very smal left hand menu, my user name does not show up on my start menu at all

Comment: @DJPTM - Please [edit] your question and indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using

Comment: Kindly check if method in the following link can help you: [Remove user name from Start Menu](https://tweaks.com/windows/36723/remove-user-name-from-start-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

The user name has been absent from the Windows 10 Start Menu starting from version 1607.

Unless you are still on a very old version of Windows,
the image you included probably comes from the cursor hovering over any one of the
left-most icons in the Start Menu.

Microsoft has not supplied any way to disable this automatic display of the names
associated with the icons.